# Reading from the first line in a multiline string

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, compare

I have a directory with files as:

```
ab_list
bd_list
cd_list
mno_list
hk_list 
pd_list
```

I have another file called testfile as outside this directory as:

```
abc
que nw

ab_list   ON   8
gs_list   ON   9
hk_list   OFF  9
bd_list   ON   7
cd_list   OFF  6
fr_list   ON   5
mno_list  ON   4
pq_list   OFF   6
jk_list   ON   7
pd_list   OFF  8
```

I want to compare the 2 and all the files with filename and ON next to it(if matched) their content should get merged into a new file called merge_file. The other files which match with testfile but have OFF, their filenames should be printed in a new_file. 
contents of ab_list bd_list and mno_list should get merged into top_file

here is the code I have tried till now:

```
from glob import glob

test_file_directory = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\"

files1 = glob("*.txt")
with open(test_file_directory+"testfile.txt","r") as f:
    files2 = [' '.join([l.split()[0],l.split()[1]]) for l in f.readlines()[3:]]

for f1 in files1:
    for f2 in files2:
        if f1[:-4]+'   ON' == f2:
            #print('match')
            with open('merge_file.txt','a') as a:
                with open(f1,'r') as r:
                    a.write(r.readlines()[1:]+'\n')
        elif f1[:-4]+'   OFF' == f2:
            #print('match')
            with open('match_file.txt','a') as a:
                with open(f1,'r') as r:
                    a.write(f"{f2} {len(r.readlines())}\n")
elif f1[:-4]+'   ON' == f2:
            #print('match')
            with open('match_file.txt','a') as a:
                with open(f1,'r') as r:
                    a.write(f"{f2} {len(r.readlines())}\n")
```

I want that the file contents being written in merge_file start being read from second line of file instead of first and match_file also has the filenames with ON next to it(it has OFF from the first elif)
`a.write(r.readlines()[1:]+'\n'` this line gives an error saying it is a string and not a list.

Comment: You can make an iterator - use the `next()` call and then continue with the rest of the values in a `for loop`.

Comment: could you help me with the code

Comment: how should i use it in this code

Comment: I might be a little bit but I'll give it a whirl

Comment: could you also have a look at the second problem mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a.write(r.readlines()[1:]+'\n')

It perform an add with r.readlines()[1:] and '\n'.

r.readlines()[1:] is a list with each line in file.

So you got error

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

What you should do is to join all line in list with '\n' by using join, like

```py
a.write('\n'.join(r.readlines()[1:])+'\n')
```

Anyway, to copy content of file, you should use f.read(), not f.readlines()

```py
a.write(r.read()+'\n')
```

To get ride first line, you can use str.partition('\n'), it divide source string to three partitions as [first_string, '\n', next_string], like

```py
a.write(r.read().partition('\n')[2]+'\n')
```

Comment: could you also have a look at my second problem

Comment: its mentioned at the end

Comment: Where sencond problem ?!

Comment: match_file also has the filenames with ON next to it(it has OFF from the first elif

Comment: and match_file should also have the merge_file (name) with number of lines

Comment: a.write(f"{f2} {len(r.readlines())}\n"), you do save the filename but with OFF and number of total lines, what the problem ? Maybe replace f2 with f1 for full and correct filename.

Comment: and how do i put merge_file (just the filename) and number of lines in match_file

Comment: The way you do :  a.write(f"{f2} {len(r.readlines())}\n")

Comment: so just replace f2 with merge_file?

Comment: 2nd elsif just do last filename in files1 and last filename in files2. It save the the filename and length for ON ?? different as your request. System alarm "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" !! : )

Comment: sorry I cant understand can you make thw change to my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216034/discussion-between-jay-las-and-jason-yang).